# Google cloud messaging registration giving null error message in android app

Tags: android, null, google-cloud-messaging

These are my two methods that are called from within my main activity, in onStart() and onStop() respectively.

```
private void registerForMessages()
{
    Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
    registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", "my project id");
    startService(registrationIntent);
}

private void unRegisterForMessages()
{
    Intent unregIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER");
    unregIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    startService(unregIntent);
}
```

Where "my project id" is my 12 digit project number with google cloud messaging for android enabled in the google api console. 
Both times that these are called, I get the following log:

```
08-10 15:07:19.370: D/GCM(791): [C2DMRegistrar.143] Send register result  null 0 0
```

I have the manifest file set up exactly the way I have seen it set up for others. My receiver class is never called anyway, the error here in the registration seems to stop it there. 
Does anyone have any idea what the error message even is telling me? What kind of things could be causing this error?

It's a little confusing trying to look it up on the android official guides, because some of it is possibly referring to the deprecated methods, and some instructions contradict each other - some say do it this way, others want you to use a register method for it.

Comment: You should include the manifest in your question (I have no way of knowing where you copied your manifest from). As for the `C2DMRegistrar` error, please include more line of log, so we can see the context of your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's ok. I think that method of doing it must actually be deprecated or something. This worked:

```
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            try
            {
            Log.d("IM", "registration thread happening");
            String regid = gcm.register("project number");
            Log.d("IM", "id: " + regid);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.d("IM register", "io exception: ");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();
```

It was giving me an IOException until I stuck it in its own thread too but seems to work ok now. I think the official guide needs updated perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

have a look on Android Push Notifications using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), PHP and MySQL
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

As per google’s documentation “Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that helps developers send data from servers to their Android applications on Android devices”. Using this service you can send data to your application whenever new data is available instead of making requests to server in timely fashion. Integrating GCM in your android application enhances user experience and saves lot of battery power.

may help you..